# Deeplink to app-specific folder in Shortcuts app

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut

The `ShortcutLinks(action:)` method of `AppIntents` opens the app's shortcut folder in the iOS Shortcuts app. I'd like to replicate the same behavior using a standard button. Something like this:

```swift
Button {
    // Deeplink to the shortcuts app here
} label: {
    Text("Open shortcut app")
}
```

According to the Apple documentation, you can use `openURL(URL(string: "shortcuts://open-shortcut?name=save%20file")!)` to open a specific action. Which works as advertised for the top level actions and `Starter Shortcuts` actions.

However, it doesn't work for any of the actions included in apps, for example:

`openURL(URL(string: "shortcuts://open-shortcut?name=buffer")!) // "File not found" error`

And what I'm trying to achieve is something slightly different: to open the app's folder (like `ShortcutLinks(action:)` does)

I've tried a few different URLs:

`openURL(URL(string: "shortcuts://shortcuts/Buffer")!) // "Shortcut not found" error`
`openURL(URL(string: "shortcuts://shortcuts/app%20shortcuts/Buffer")!) // "Shortcut not found" error`

None seem to work.

I guess the question is: what is the deeplink/URL `ShortcutLinks(action:)` uses?